# View Models and their effect on Model Binding in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, model-binding

I believe ViewModels are a good thing. I have just been trying to convert part of my application to use them. However I may have bumped into a side effect and that is their effect on Model Binding, in particular the default "checking" behaviour of the Radiobutton helper:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Value",Item.Value)
```

The above works if the default model has a "Value" property off it. However if I use a ViewModel then Value may be one level down, ie:

No VM

```
Model.Value
```

With VM:

```
Model.Content.Value;
MyContent = Model.Content.Value;
```

This no longer works:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Value",Item.Value)
```

Perhaps I need to tweak the RB helper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Content.Value)
```

Comment: Excellent tip. SO is brilliant :) Obviously with this approach one is populating the model directly. What would happen if one created a local variable off this ie "myContentValue". I guess this is "By Value" and would need to be assigned back to the Model object. ----- or is this not the way to do things in the View.... ie always populate the Model directly as opposed to via a variable?

Comment: Yes... always populate the model/view model directly. There's no need to use separate variables. That's the purpose of all `@Html` helpers that end in `For` in ASP.NET MVC. They do the hard work/data-model binding for you.